# Why use 1.008 g/mol instead of 1.0079 g/mol calculating the number of moles in 75.0 g H_2 molecules?

Tags: stoichiometry

Why are figures removed from the calculation for values that are known in more detail? E.g. if you want to calculate the number of moles in 75.0 g H2 molecules. Why should one here use
for the relative atomic mass/molar mass of H 1,008 u or g/mol instead of 1,0079 u or g/mol?
What is the purpose of this?
In addition to that, should one round interim results like the substance amount, the molar mass or should one just round the final result?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Please note that the proper term for "number of moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms".

Comment: Think about the error of input data and error propagation.

Comment: (I deleted the last comment, I thought that 1.0079g/mol was the molar mass of H). The molar mass of H lies between [1.00784:1.00811] g/mol, so why use 1.008 g/mol?

Comment: H molar mas has relative error circa 1e-4. the given mass has rel.error circa 1.3e-3. n=m/V has relative error circa sqrt((1e-4)^2 + (1.3e-3)^2)=sqrt(1e-8 + 1.8e-6)=circa 1.3e-3. Error of M has minimal impact on the error of n,in contrary to the error of m.

Comment: Similar illustrative example: if you have expression a . b, and if you know 3 valid digits of a, it is useless to use e.g. 5 or more valid digits of b, even if they are known.( unless computed, in such case it does not matter ). But the result error is determined by the more errorneous parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, mostly cause we don't care.

In my lab if I'm measuring 3mL - 12mL of a liquid I use a syringe that only has lines on the syringe every 0.2mL. So if I were to be measuring, say, 9mL, I would only have about 2 [sig figs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). Also, to be honest, I sometimes don't really care if I'm off by a mL. So in doing the math I'd round 1.0079 to 1 because it's easier and the extra precision will be lost when I measure out the chemical anyway.

As for when to round. You should always keep one or two extra sig figs during the calculation and round at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## Molecular mass of hydrogen

**For $\ce{H2}$ there are 2.016 g/mol (4 significant figures)**

The [IUPAC value [1.00784, 1.00811]](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/pac/88/3/article-p265.xml?language=en) indicates that there is significant isotopic variation in the atomic mass of hydrogen due to the abundances of $\ce{^1H}$ and $\ce{^2H}$ (comparatively there is too little $\ce{^3H}$ to matter). So for hydrogen in some arbitrary compound it would be expected that  $1.00784 <= m_\mathrm{H} <= 1.00811$.

[image]

If you look at the [individual isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_hydrogen#List_of_isotopes) the atomic mass is known to much greater precision.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
Nuclide &   Isotopic\ mass & abundance \\ \hline
\ce{^1H} & 1.00782503224(9) & 0.999885(70)\\ \hline
\ce{^2H} & 2.01410177811(12) & 0.000115(70)\\ \hline
\ce{^3H} & 3.01604928199(23) & trace \\ \hline
\end{array}

## Rounding

With a modern calculator try to avoid intermediate calculations as much as possible to avoid rounding errors.

If you do calculate intermediate results which can't be stored in the calculator, then I'd write down two extra digits for the intermediate result.

Round only the final calculation to the proper number of significant figures.

Comment: You write "*molecular mass*", but it looks like you report the value of *molar mass* (in g/mol). These are not the same thing, especially in the context of the question.